# My auth register is not submitting to database after i modiy it in laravel 5.8

Tags: php

i added phone number and gender to my auth register and my auth reg is not displaying any error message or submitting to database this is my registercontroller.php

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'sex' =>['required','string'],
            'phone'=>[ 'required','numeric']
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'sex'=>$data['sex'],
            'phone'=>$data['phone']
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: Welcome. Have you added the fields to the `$fillable` array in your user model?

Comment: is your `App\User` model included in the registration controller?

Comment: it was included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done migration for the added column into the database?